# What should I put in the "Supporting Files" folder of XCode?

Tags: xcode, macos

Upon creating a new Cocoa project in XCode, the program creates a "Supporting Files" group/folder which contains some files. The question is, what should I put in this folder? My whole source code? Just some particular files? Nothing?

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please let me know what was wrong about the question

Comment: anything make sense to you and others using the project

Comment: What I'm asking is what would make sense to put there? If it is completely arbitrary then they wouldn't have added it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode files and folders clean structure and organization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087244/xcode-files-and-folders-clean-structure-and-organization). Also see [Where is the RESOURCES folder in the new xCode4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507997/where-is-the-resources-folder-in-the-new-xcode4-2).